# Is there a way to play both BF1942 expansions at the same time?

Tags: battlefield-1942

I finally got the **Battlefield 1942** official expansion packs **Road to Rome** and **Secret Weapons of WWII**.

I can enable them via the main menu, or load them with a shortcut with "+game XPack1" or "+game XPack2" on it, but activating one disables the other.

Is there a way to enable both expansions at the same time?

I want to have the secret weapons on the Italian maps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret [this post](https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654625320466014/) exactly, but it seems someone got the DLCs working together. Can you check?

Comment: @Joachim Nice find. I will investigate, although messing with registry files sounds scary.

Comment: Just make sure you make a backup. I don't think I *ever* had a problem with messing around in the register. And maybe check the .reg files beforehand, to see if they only make edits in the appropriate locations (probably all starting with EA, or Electronic Arts, or something similar).

Answer (score -1):

That's only possible  when you start your own  dedicated server or  join a server online that's running multiple modifications of the game

Comment: I only told the truth  if you run a dedicated server  you can edit the con files  to spawn custom objects  you can also let this be done locally so you can only see the server yourself and join it.